# How to get the current selected view everytime when view is changed from vscode API

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-api

I've added a new view in vscode while making an extension.

I want to run a function everytime when this view is opened.

Is there any vscode method to run a function everytime this view is opened or when user come on this view.

[image]

Comment: you only created a **View Container**, you have to add a View to this Container and a provider to give the view content, the view can be a Tree View or a WebviewView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your view is a `TreeView`, you can listen to its visibility:

```js
const treeViewVisibilityListener = this.tabView.onDidChangeVisibility(async event => {
    console.log("here");
});
context.subscriptions.push(treeViewVisibilityListener);
```

`event` will have the values `{visible: true}` or `{visible: false}` depending on whether it was opened or not.  It also works for when the view is hidden or unhidden from the Activity Bar or Panel or Secondary Bar - depending on where the user moves it.

If your view is a `Webview` you can use the same `.onDidChangeVisibility` listener.

These do not fire if the View clicked on/revealed is not yours.